# Making distributable flow-typed packages with third-party type dependencies

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

I have a library that is using Flow types. It also has a dependency, and part of its interface includes type definitions from the `flow-typed` file for that library. I'm using `flow-copy-source` to ensure there are `.js.flow` files present in the installed package.

The problem I'm having is that when the consumer of this library imports my module, the type imports from the dependency are also imported, but the consumer now has to install its own copy of the `flow-typed` definitions for that dependency. Normally that'd be fine, but if that consuming code has a different *version* of that dependency itself, there isn't a way to avoid conflicting definitions.

To put this concretely, my library is an HTTP service wrapper using `axios@0.18.x` and has imports like this:

```
import type { Axios, AxiosXHRConfig } from 'axios';
```

`AxiosXHRConfig` in version `0.18.x` of the `flow-typed` definition takes two type parameters. In the meantime, the *consuming* application is using an older version of `axios` and has a different version of axios library definition for that older version. Since both library definitions have:

```
declare module "axios" {
  // ...
}
```

...that `import type { ... } from 'axios'` in the library doesn't have a way to resolve to the `flow-typed/npm/axios_v0.18.x.js` in the library instead of the consuming application's `flow-typed/npm/axios_v0.17.x.js`.

Short of duplicating the `flow-typed` definitions in the library, how do you make distributable flow-typed packages with global type dependencies that can be safely consumed by other flow projects?

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking this approach as a manual workaround until I hear of a more automatic way to do this:

1. Create a `/src/interface.js` flow file with only the public interface for my library
2. Have my client class implement this public interface
3. Discontinue using `flow-copy-source`
4. Publish both my `/src` and transpiled `/lib` directory.
5. Add an `index.js` and `index.js.flow` that wipe away the typing for the implementation of the interface, like this:

index.js:

```
module.exports = require('./lib/client').default;
```

index.js.flow:

```
// @flow

import type { FooClient as _FooClient } from './src/interface';
export type FooClient = _FooClient;

const Client: Class<FooClient> = require('./lib/client').default;

export default Client;
```

This solves the original problem because the third-party dependency is now effectively encapsulated and doesn't reach outside of the exposed interface.